# Should I extend JPanel for custom class rendering in Swing?

Tags: java, swing

I have a custom class representing spaceships that will rotate and fly around on the screen. However, I realized that if I want to use Swing, I have to render the ships via paintComponent().

This is the method I was going to use for rendering:

```
    public void render(Graphics g){

        AffineTransform original = ((Graphics2D) g).getTransform();
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d.rotate(orientation, getGamePosition().x, getGamePosition().y);
        g2d.drawImage(spriteDefault, position.x, position.y, null);
        g2d.setTransform(original);
    }
```

So in order to use Swing, should I extend JPanel so that I can override paintComponent and put this code inside that method, or should it be JComponent, or some other way?

I just want to make sure I'm on the right track here...

Comment: `JPanel` should be fine.  `JComponent` by default is not opaque, whereas `JPanel` is.  I doubt there would be much difference between the two...

Comment: I would consider the `JPanel`/`JComponent` as you "paint surface", it's what you paint onto.  I would make each entity capable of been rendered individually, so that they would have there own paint/render methods, which you pass an instance of `Graphics2D` and any other game state information you might need.  This way, it's a simple matter of looping through a list of entities to get them to paint.  Also, don't put any logic into this process, painting paints, that all it does...

Comment: where would I call their own paint/render methods from?

Comment: Well, since painting occurs through `paintComponent`, `paintComponent`... ;)

Comment: If you haven't already done so, take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for details about how painting is accomplished in Swing

Comment: Yeah I've been working my way through it. Thanks for your answers on both my questions.